# How to impersonate logged on user?

Tags: powershell, impersonation, security-context, advapi32

I need to impersonate logged on user.
It's required because of ps security context.

Let me explain.
I have one win service.
And one dll library with whole logic.
And two different clients(.exe and ps) 
which use this service via dll.

When I start .exe and call win service
everything is ok. But when i start ps
and try to use the same win service method
with the same arguments it gives me this error:
(and also i start exe and ps with the same user
on the same machine)

Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.

Actually I try to use current account for impersonation.
So I've found following method:

```
function ImpersonateLoggedOnUser
{
param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [IntPtr]
        $TokenHandle
    )

    $SUCCESS = $Advapi32::ImpersonateLoggedOnUser($TokenHandle); $LastError = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()

    if(-not $SUCCESS)
    {
        throw "ImpersonateLoggedOnUser Error: $(([ComponentModel.Win32Exception] $LastError).Message)"
    }
}
```

But I can't call it.
It gives me following error:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Where is `$Advapi32` defined / what is it? It looks like this code is missing a large chunk of P/Invoke code, probably written in C# and in-lined with `Add-Type` or in a module that needs importing, wrapping around the advapi32.dll.

Comment: yes, you right. I defined it with error. so it helps me. thanks.